# Creating a customer journey map from persona

Tags: usability, website-design, personas, user-journey, journey-map

I was asked to create personas and customer journey map using analytical data and other online data (Without talking to the actual customers).

So, I created a few buyer personas based on some data (Google analytics, Forums, Social media feedback). Now, the next step is to map that into the Customer Journey, but I am lacking the technical and practical knowledge regarding this step. Is there anyone has done this before, from buyer personas to the customer journey?

*The requirement is to redesign the website, and it is a retail website.*

Answer (score 1):

I assume the Buyer Persona is your target customer? I.e., the person you will target for the redesign.

You're creating a largely provisional Persona and Customer Journey Map, which is fine. Just keep in mind you likely have some assumptions baked into it as you've not used additional customer research to inform it. It's good to use analytical data and other available sources as a start.

Basic stages:

1. Define target persona
2. Define scenario or use case. I.e., purchase experience, browsing experience, etc.
3. Define stages (high-level goals) persona goes through from start to finish; start with the outcome then work up to it.
4. For each stage, define meaningful information such as: Needs, Questions they are thinking, Actions they are doing, Problems, Satisfaction, etc.

Some helpful resources:

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/customer-journey-mapping/

http://www.mappingexperiences.com/

Comment: Hi RPJ, thanks for the information, really useful! appreciated.